# tcl tdbc::odbc package and passing parameters to a query

Tags: tcl, tdbc

This is the first time I am trying to use tdbc package (ODBC connection) and I cannot figure out how to pass parameters into the query. Here is the code:

```
set dsnName dsn1
set username user1
set password xxxxx
set connStr "DSN=$dsnName; UID=$username; PWD=$password;"
tdbc::odbc::connection create db $connStr

set rows [db allrows {SELECT DISTINCT [Address] FROM [Customers] WHERE [Apt Number]='3-b'}]
```

This is working. However, I would like to pass '3-b' to the query. So I tried:

```
set queryValues [dict create apt 3-b]
set rows [db allrows {SELECT DISTINCT [Address] FROM [Customers] WHERE [Apt Number]=':apt'} $queryValues]
```

But this gave me an error ([Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]String data, right truncation) or something similar.
I tried different formats and nothing working. What am I doing wrong?

(Based on Glenn's answer I also tried:

```
set stmt [db prepare {SELECT DISTINCT [Address] FROM [Customers] WHERE [Apt Number]=:apt}]
set params [dict create apt "3-b"]
set rows [$stmt allrows $params]
```

same error ([    1][Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]String data, right truncation)

but this is working.

```
 set stmt [db prepare {SELECT DISTINCT [Address] FROM [Customers] WHERE [Apt Number]='3-b'}]
set rows [$stmt allrows]
```

I must also add that tclodbc package worked fine here. See the code below

```
package require tclodbc
#<connect to database>
#query
set aptNo "3-b"
set query "SELECT DISTINCT \[Address\] FROM \[Customers\] WHERE \[Apt Number\]=?"
set dbResult [$dbConn $query [list $aptNo]]
```

working fine in tclodbc package, but similar code failing in tdbc package.

--Suresh

Comment: What is the definition of the `Address` column?

Comment: @Donal, it is varchar(255)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a [prepared statement](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TdbcCmd/tdbc_statement.htm)

```
# note, no quotes around the placeholder param name.
set stmt [db prepare {SELECT DISTINCT [Address] FROM [Customers] WHERE [Apt Number]=:apt}]
set params [dict create apt "3-b"]
set rows [$stmt allrows $params]
```

Or you could just create an "apt" local variable:

```
set apt "3-b"
set rows [$stmt allrows]
```

Comment: Thanks Glenn, but prepared statement also giving same error :( . Is this something in the database? This is SQL database

Comment: @Suresh, why are you so sure your *input* data does fit into the target column? When the SQL Server tells you about your data would have been truncated it means that you, say, submit a string of length 50 to match against a column of length 30.

Comment: @Suresh, now the reasons for this to happen might be different, including improper charset conversions (like somehow directly passing UTF-8-encoded string containing non-ASCII characters to SQL Server). All-in-all, I'd start with installing the SQL Server Profiler, starting a trace here and capturing the exchange of your application and the server. Another approach is to capture the on-the-wire traffic using Microsoft Network Monitor--its dissectors support MS-TDS protocol just fine. Wireshark would work, too.